# How to change a string of numbers, spaces, and commas, to an arraylist of integers

Tags: java, string, arraylist, numbers, int

I want to figure out how to take a string of numbers, spaces, and commas, and turn it into an arraylist of integers.

For example, the input is 1, 2, 3, 4, 11, 23
and the output would be an arraylist containing those same numbers but in integer form instead of a string.

I've experimented with some code to remove the spaces and commas then add the numbers to an arraylist but I just can't seem to get my if statements to work. Feel free to change anything about the nature of the input or anything like that, it is very flexible.
Here is the important bit of what I have now if it helps;

```
numCheck = Kd.nextLine();
        for(int i = 1; i < numCheck.length(); i++) {
            if(String.valueOf(numCheck.charAt(1)) == " ") {
                num = numCheck.charAt(0);
                System.out.println(num+"a");
                nums.add(num);  
                break;
            }
            else if((String.valueOf(numCheck.charAt(i-1))) == " "){//1 2 34
                    num = numCheck.charAt(i);
                    System.out.println(num + "b");
                    nums.add(num);  
                    i+=1;

                }
            else if(String.valueOf(numCheck.charAt(i-1)) != " ")
                {
                    numsTogether = numCheck.charAt(i-1) + "" + numCheck.charAt(i);
                    System.out.println(numsTogether + "c");
                    nums.add(Integer.parseInt(numsTogether));
                    i++;
                }
```

Any help is appreciated,
Thanks.

Comment: Did you try using the `String` class's `split` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this in one line by using java 8 streams using `String.trim()` will trim all the spaces and `Integer.valueOf()` change string to Integer

```
List<Integer> l= Arrays.stream("1, 2, 3, 4, 11, 23".split(",")).map(item->Integer.valueOf(item.trim())).collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(l);
```

Comment: Thanks, that works great, could explain to me exactly what that line of code is doing, especially the bit with .map, sorry Im a bit of a noob

Comment: just asking do you have idea on lambda expression, so map will take every string that was in array ( "1, 2, 3, 4, 11, 23".split(",") this will create a string []), and in map i'm converting every string to integer after trimming string using `String.trim()`, if you have still question i will guide you to tutorials

Answer (score 2):

I would split on comma surrounded by optional white-space, stream that, map each token to an `int` and then collect it to a `List`. Like,

```
String numCheck = "1, 2, 3, 4, 11, 23";
List<Integer> al = Arrays.stream(numCheck.split("\\s*,\\s*"))
        .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(al);
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Split on commas using String.split.
2. For each element in the array, call String.trim().
3. Use Integer.valueOf() to convert this element to a number
4. Add it to your list.